# present perfect tense usage

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, active-voice

I have a question about present perfect tense.
It would be great if you could help me figure that out. Today I was listening to "Everything has changed" and I noticed that when I talk about something that is already started and affected to now or (a period around now), we always use present perfect, but what I do not understand is this part. I will write these sentences to compare.

*S+have/has+v.3+Object*

> I have changed my car.

I changed my car and now I am using a new car. the old car does not belong to me anymore.

*S +have/has+v.3*

> Everything has changed

In this case I don't get it clearly. Actually I've heard this so many times, and I understand it. For example, when I talked to my friend about the computer game. The path was updated and there was everything new.  And my friend said "Everything has changed".

I'm confused when I compare it to another sentence like

> I have changed my mind.
>   I have changed my phone number.
>   I have changed my wallet.

but for "everything has changed" I think it could not be changed itself.

Why don't we say "Everything has been changed" instead because it does not have an object?

Comment: I **think** you're asking about a verb, *change* in this instance, which can be transitive as well as intransitive. It doesn't seem that you're asking about the present perfect tense *per se*.

Comment: sorry i thought it was present perfect since i was trying to compare the verb in present perfect. Sorry for make this hard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the answer to your question you need to know that *change* is an *ergative verb*. Wikipedia defines [ergative verbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergative_verb) as follows:

> In linguistics, an *ergative verb* is a verb that can be either
>   transitive or intransitive, and whose subject when intransitive
>   corresponds to its direct object when transitive.

So, in the sentence *I have changed my phone number*, *change* is a transitive verb with *I* as the subject and *phone number* is the object.

But *change* can also be used intransitively, as in *My phone number has changed*. We can see how, in Wikipedia's definition, the "*subject when intransitive corresponds to its direct object when transitive*".

Another common ergative verb is *break*:

> I broke my watch (object).
>
> My watch (subject) broke.

Wikipedia lists the following as common ergative verbs:

> Ergative verbs can be divided into several categories:
>
> - Verbs  suggesting a change of state — break, burst, form, heal, melt, tear, transform
> - Verbs of cooking — bake, boil, cook, fry
> - Verbs of movement —  move, shake, sweep, turn, walk
> - Verbs involving vehicles — drive, fly, reverse, run, sail

You can also say *Everything has been changed*, in which case you are using the transitive *change* in the passive. The difference between *Everything has changed* and *Everything has been changed* is that the latter implies that there is an agent behind the change, in a way that the former does not necessarily.

Comment: I've never heard about this before. I'll have a look carefully and thank you so much for your helping. :) Now I got a new topic to study. have a good day.

Comment: @jit: You could at least give old Shoe an up vote for this answer before moving on. (+1)

Comment: @Robusto. Thanks, old Shoe is good, and right! But a couple of times I've got an embarrassingly high number of upvotes for a very short SWR answer, so things even out in the end!

Comment: @Shoe: It's what I call the SE Conundrum, a variation of [Parkinson's Law of Triviality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality), which "is C. Northcote Parkinson's 1957 argument that organizations give disproportionate weight to trivial issues." Here the bikeshedding involves drastic up-voting for trivial answers while worthy ones go unnoticed.

Comment: Hi I was triying to vote up your answer but it stated that "vote up requires 15 reputation". Sorry I could not vote for you this time, but thank you so much for reminding me to vote up. I'm new for this website so I don't know the tradition.  Thank you for letting me know :)

Comment: @Robusto. Thanks for introducing me to a new term. I had never heard of _bikeshedding_ before.

Answer (score 0):

This is all about these two meanings of "change"

> **change**
>
> transitive verb
>
> 1 :  to **make** different:
>
> a :  to make different in some particular
> but short of short of conversion into something else :  alter, modify
>
> intransitive verb
>
> 1 :  to **become** different in one or more respects
> without becoming something else
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary

i.e.

to make **[something else]** different

to become **[/himself/herself/oneself/]** different

Comment: Thank you :) So if it is intransitive I can say "The season has changed" "The time has changed" "My life has changed" thank you for replying me :)